# Confirm inputed data in input box and display it in show box with ENTER hit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a code to write me selected values of tree structure in show box on other side of page. Now in some lines of tree structure i must add html input boxes, so that user can input data. Now i need that those inputed data are shown on show box on other side of page, when user input data in input box in tree structure and press ENTER button. With code
     `<input type="text" placeholder="Enter new continent">` the whole input box is shown on show box on other side of page, not the inputed data from users.

Code which shows selected data from tree structure in show box on other side of page is working that when i click on element of tree structure (line) it's shown in show box on other side of page.

Now i need to do, that when i click on input box (Enter new continent), this input box is NOT shown on show box on other side of page. Than user input data in input box, and press enter. The inputed data are now shown in show box on other side of page. Any idea how should i do this?

Here is working sample of my page: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvQxeL

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like that ?

```
var continent = prompt("Please enter the continent name", "Continent");
```